# How do i detect an app that takes most are of the screen?

Tags: windows, detect

I am working on a script that would detect what app the user is currently looking at. That means if the app takes more than 80% of the screen and if it's "on top" of the screen print the name of the application on the console.

I would like to know if it's possible and if so, how? I apprieciete any programming language, thanks for any responses.

Comment: GetForegroundWindow() to find the window in the foreground, GetWindowThreadProcessId() to find out what process owns that window, GetWindowRect() to find its size.

Comment: What language is that?